# csshooks for all css numerical values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there any way to write a csshooks for all css numerical values so that everything is considered to be in "px" and hence saving you the headache of converting between string and integer every time you want to make calculations on them ? I'm not just talking about top/left/width/height ... even things like fontSize